# Unexpected error while executing: -- Error while Launching activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vaibhav.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

...........................................................................

Above is my code , which looks fine but i don't know why I am getting the below Error ...

**Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.vaibhav.myapplication/com.example.vaibhav.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Error while Launching activity**

.................
Also their is one thing , my , **am start** command is taking package name twice though it is declared correctly in

**am start -n "com.example.vaibhav.myapplication/com.example.vaibhav.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category**

Answer (score 0):

You should use fully classified class name for activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

> **android:name**
>
> The name of the class that implements the activity, a subclass of Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity"). However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to the package name specified in the  element.

For more info refer [Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm)

Comment: Yes I had Already Used name as the complete name ,, and then I even tried using .Mainactivity .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for some reason a wrong adb command is generated and being stuck in the project.

For me cleaning the project, closing then importing the project solved the problem.

Maybe even invalidate cashes and restart is also enough